# Warning - assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, types

First of all im sorry if you're trying hard to understand me. My English is not that well.
I'm studying Computer Engineering and this is my first year. I'm learning about C programming. 
I want to write a code for a card game but i can't fix this problem that im having with the pointers.

```
    const char cards[][30] = {"spades_one", ...};
    char is_it_used[][1] = {"1",...};
    char player_1_deck[7][30], player_2_deck[7][30], player_1[1][20], player_2[1][20];
    char *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4;

s1 = &cards[0];
s2 = &is_it_used[0];
s3 = &player_1_deck[0];
s4 = &player_2_deck[0];
```

I'm getting the "assignment from incompatible pointer type" warning because of the s1, s2, s3 and s4. What should i do? How can i fix this problem? Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is because the four arrays you define are *two dimensional*.

That is why you have the error.

```
const char cards[][30] = {"spades_one", ...}
char is_it_used[][1] = {"1",...}
char player_1_deck[7][30], player_2_deck[7][30], player_1[1][20], player_2[1][20];
char *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4;

s1 = &cards[0][0]; 
s2 = &is_it_used[0][0];
s3 = &player_1_deck[0][0];
s4 = &player_2_deck[0][0];
```

the above should work

but it really depends what you want to achieve with `s1`, `s2` etc.

it may be more appropriate to have

```
s1=player_1_deck[0];
```

for example or

```
s1=player_1_deck[2];
```

etc.

so that `s1` points at an individual card

Answer (score 0):

In these assignment statements

```
s1 = &cards[0];
s2 = &is_it_used[0];
s3 = &player_1_deck[0];
s4 = &player_2_deck[0];
```

the left operands have the type char * while the right operands have types correspondingly `char ( * )[30]`, `char ( * )[1]`, `char ( * )[30]`, `char ( * )[30]` and there is no implicit conversion from the type `char *` to the type of one of listed pointers.

If you want that pointers s1, s4 point to the first characters of the first strings of the multi-dimensional arrays you can just write

```
s1 = cards[0];
s2 = is_it_used[0];
s3 = player_1_deck[0];
s4 = player_2_deck[0];
```

Pay attention to that this array

```
char is_it_used[][1] = {"1",...};
```

does not contain strings. In fact this declaration is equivalent to

```
char is_it_used[][1] = { '1',...};
                         ^^^
```